# Closure confusion: accessing objects when jQuery promise is done

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, requirejs, promise

I have an AMD module like so:

```
define ['backbone', 'jquery', 'someObj'], (Backbone, $, someObj) ->

  class MyModel extends Backbone.Model
    # some options

  foo = new MyModel
  bar = new MyModel

  foo.fetch().done ->
    # Here I want to do things with foo and bar now that the fetch is complete
    # but they are not visible
    # Backbone, $, someObj, and MyModel are all visible, however
```

Why can I access objects like `someObj`, but not `foo` or `bar`? Also, is this not the right way to simulate synchronous code, viz. to run code that can only run after the promise is resolved? Essentially, I want to:

1. Instantiate `foo` and `bar`
2. Fetch `foo` and/or `bar` from server
3. Do all the things to `foo` and `bar` that need to wait on the fetch

It seems that done can contain actions that are either generic (e.g. `console.log "Done"`) or only access the parameters passed into it from the promise. I guess I need to use a different closure structure or something, but I'm just drawing a blank on how to do what I want. (I'm not sure if this is something I'm only experiencing because I'm inside an AMD module so I'm tagging this with RequireJS too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting this into the **Try Coffeescript** REPL at http://coffeescript.org/...

```
define ['backbone', 'jquery', 'someObj'], (Backbone, $, someObj) ->

  class MyModel extends Backbone.Model
    # some options

  foo = new MyModel
  bar = new MyModel

  foo.fetch().done ->
    # Here I want to do things with foo and bar now that the fetch is complete
    # but they are not visible
    # Backbone, $, someObj, and MyModel are all visible, however
    console.log foo, bar
```

Produces this:

```
/*snip boilerplate*/
define(['backbone', 'jquery', 'someObj'], function(Backbone, $, someObj) {
  var MyModel, bar, foo, _ref;
  MyModel = (function(_super) {
    __extends(MyModel, _super);

    function MyModel() {
      _ref = MyModel.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
      return _ref;
    }

    return MyModel;

  })(Backbone.Model);
  foo = new MyModel;
  bar = new MyModel;
  return foo.fetch().done(function() {
    return console.log(foo, bar);
  });
});
```

It would appear that your closure *should* have access to `foo` and `bar`. So I'm not sure if the problem you are getting is a different one than variable access within the `done` callback.

It sounds like you will have to debug the code in the browser in order to verify you can see the variables you should be seeing.

Comment: Yes, you're right; this works. Apparently, I've oversimplified the example somehow. I'll try to update it to reflect more of the real code.